# kate external tools [solved]

Tags: scripts, home-directory, kate

Kate has a very useful feature: recall external tools, and it let you add your own (bash) scripts.

However I noticed that these scripts **must** be in /home folder: if they are outside, even symlinked in /home folder they aren't see (and therefore they can't work).

Is there a solution to put a script outside the home, and only *symlink* to home, so that it can work in Kate?

#### EDIT

I tried to fix this issue adding as new $PATH for my scripts the folder where I have my scripts, but I didn't manage to solve. Kate doesn't see these scripts.

#### EDIT

Kate version: 20.04.0

#### EDIT

As I have said in a comment, perhaps the problem is not a Kate problem, but a bash one, because also in a terminal I cant't execute a bash script outside the home directory, even though I have added the path of a given folder in my .bashrc, this way:
`export PATH="/mnt/dati/schede/web/:$PATH"`
At this point I don't know if I should change the title of this thread (= "problem with .bashrc" ?)

### Solved!

In effect the problem was the *partition permissions*: solved adding "exec" in fstab to that partition.

Comment: Please mention the version of Kate. Features may have been added/removed depending on the version.

Comment: If you don't get support here, please try asking at [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/), [KDE Community Forums](https://forum.kde.org), or [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/).

Comment: And by any chance are you using a snap version of Kate or a backports ppa? I think Kate 20.04 isn't the default in *buntu 20.04.

Comment: Thank you. I have KDE Neon, so KDE apps are updated to the last version, I believe. No snap, but from official repo.

Comment: According to https://kate-editor.org/post/2019/2019-09-21-external-tools-plugin/, "You can either provide an absolute path, or your executable must be in the PATH environment variable." I haven't used this tool myself.

Comment: I tried with absolute path: nothing to do. However perhaps is a bash, not a Kate problem, because also with a terminal I get an error message (permission denied), even after a "chmod u+x". I don't understand...